# DWP file is not updated in the web part gallery by the stsadm upgradesolution command

Tags: 2007, solution-package, upgrade, web-part

I am trying to update a DWP file in the web part gallery by using stsadm upgradesolution. Here is what I am doing:

1. Created a web part, put it in feature, packaged it in solution by WSPBuilder, deployed it. Worked absolutely fine.
2. Updated the xml of my dwp file.
3. Compiled the project again.
4. Build wsp file through WSPBuilder again.
5. executed stsadm's upgradesolution command.
6. Once completed, checked the assembly date in GAC and it reflects the time of my upgrade which means it is copied during upgrade. Great.
7. Checked the dwp file in Web Part Gallery but it is not updated and still showing the old file.

Am I missing something? How can I upgrade my dwp files through upgradesolution?

Answer (score 1):

Try retract and remove first, then install your updated wsp.

Comment: Thanks Carl, but it will kill the purpose of upgrading. I wanted to avoid retracting and removing to keep things simple but it looks like that there is no other way .

Answer (score 0):

did you run IISRESET after your upgrade?

Comment: Hi Brian! Yes, I tried but no benefit.